# Simple shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts, iptables

I am quite inexperienced when it comes to Linux and now I am setting up the system. What I want to do is to write a shell script, that will do two things:

1. Start `i2prouter` - as I do not want it to run all the time as a daemon as it takes lots of traffic.
2. Will run new iptables procedures that will set new rules for the internet.

I made a new iptables rules file (called `iptables.up.rules`)

When I do it from terminal I write the following

```
i2prouter start
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

But if I just put it in the `.sh` file and make it executable, it does not seem to work.

Comment: This might be better off on http://unix.stackexchange.com because it does not appear to be specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: This question is relevant to Ubuntu, and the OP chose to post it to Ubuntu, which makes it on-topic. I would not vote to close it as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Shell scripts must start with the following line:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Or `/bin/bash`, or whatever shell you want to use. So your script file should look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
i2prouter start
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to include shebang ( `#!/bin/sh` ) and grant execution privilege ( `chmod u+x script.sh` )